# functional programming: compare elements of associative array to elements in another associative array where each element must be compared differently

Tags: functional-programming, comparison

Scenerio:

You're uploading a video to multiple end-points, each with different restrictions. We have restrictions in an associative array as such:

```
EndPointRestrictions = [  
     point1 = [  
          resolution: 4000,  
          extensions: [mp4, mov]  
     ],
     point2 = [
          resolution: 1080,  
          extensions: [mp4, mov]  
     ],      
]
```

We get details about the video from something like ffmpeg. We'll format it in much the same way.

```
details = [
    resolution: 1080,
    extensions: [mp4, mov]
]
```

We need to know if a video is compatible with an endpoint and each value for comparison needs to be compared in a different manner (is resolution greater than end point accepts, is extension IN the list of acceptable extensions).

We have a list of functions to represent the differences as such.

```
comparisons = [
    resolution: function(a, b) {
        return (a <= b) ? true : false
    },
    extension: function(a, b) {
        return (a in b) ? true : false
    }
}
```

If a particular value is incompatible we need to record the incompatibility for each endpoint and what the value should be to be compatible with that endpoint, then we can trans-code it later. In procedural style the algorithm could be something similar to the following (FYI, this is all pseudocode and not tested):

```
extractIncompatibilities(details, EndPointRestrictions , comparisons ) {
    incompatibilities = []
    foreach(EndPointRestrictions  as name => conditions) {
        result = [version: name, conditions = []]
        foreach(details as detail => value) {
            if (comparisons [detail](value, conditions[detail])) {
                result[conditions][detail] = conditions[detail]
            }
        }
        if (length(result[conditions])) {
            incompatibilities[] = result
        }
    }
    return incompatibilities
}
```

How could I write this in a functional paradigm?  What data structures would I use and how could I represent the algorithm?

Comment: The algorithm wouldn't look much different from what you already have - you filter the endpoints by looking for each whether all conditions are met. What data structure you would use depends a great deal on the actual programming language you're gonna use, heterogenous associative arrays like you are using them are rather uncommon.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your response Bergi. I had the expectation that the algorithm would be cut up in to a few functions. Let me as you this, if you could could choose the language based what data-structure you would use like to use, what language and data-structure would it be and why?

Comment: TBH, I don't know a statically typed language that has such a kind of heterogenous [applicative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor) datastructure :-/